# Get textbox value after append - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, append

First I'll append some value to a textbox using jQUery :

```
$('#textboxId').val('someval');
```

Now the value is empty, when I see in console.log

[image]

This will not work, since the value is empty.

```
var someVar = $('#textboxId').val();
```

How do I get the appended value again in jquery?

Comment: First: Your screenshot is not the console.log, it's the browser inspector.  In chrome this is "Elements" and shows the html, not the values - if you click on "Console" next to this, you get the console.  In there, type `$("textboxId").val()" and press enter.   It will be 'someval'.

Comment: Second: You are not "appending" a value, you are "replacing" the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This will not work, since the value is empty.

No, your code is valide and will work, you can notice that the value is added to the input field, but the value attribute always shows the default value. Browser Inspector never displayed the current value in the attribute. The current value is always visible just on the screen.

```js
$('#textboxId').val('someval');

alert($('#textboxId').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='textboxId'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('#textboxId').append('someval');

var someVar = $('#textboxId').val();
```